# Sort an array by two fields

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to summarise this unordered 2d array:

```
[
  [3.0, 1.0, 4.0], 
  [2.0, 1.0, 1.0], 
  [1.0, 1.0, 6.0], 
  [1.0, 1.0, 1.0], 
  [3.0, 2.0, 5.0], 
  [2.0, 2.0, 1.0], 
  [3.0, 1.0, 1.0],
  [1.0, 1.0, 4.0],
  [1.0, 2.0, 3.0],
  [3.0, 1.0, 2.0],
  [2.0, 1.0, 1.0],
  [2.0, 2.0, 2.0]
]
```

I'm able to order it by the first then second columns like so:

```
[
[1.0, 1.0, 6.0], 
[1.0, 1.0, 1.0], 
[1.0, 1.0, 4.0], 
[1.0, 2.0, 3.0], 
[2.0, 1.0, 1.0], 
[2.0, 1.0, 1.0], 
[2.0, 2.0, 1.0], 
[2.0, 2.0, 2.0], 
[3.0, 1.0, 4.0], 
[3.0, 1.0, 1.0], 
[3.0, 1.0, 2.0], 
[3.0, 2.0, 5.0]
]
```

Using this code:

```
function sortData(myArr) {

  // sort on second column, asc
  myArr.sort(function (element_a, element_b) {
    return element_a[1] - element_b[1];
  });
  // sort on first column, asc
  myArr.sort(function (element_a, element_b) {
    return element_a[0] - element_b[0];
  });

  return myArr;
}
```

Ultimately, the result below is what I'm trying to get (sum of third column, grouped by 1st and 2nd in ascending order):

```
[
[1.0, 1.0, 11.0], 
[1.0, 2.0, 3.0], 
[2.0, 1.0, 2.0], 
[2.0, 2.0, 3.0], 
[3.0, 1.0, 7.0], 
[3.0, 2.0, 5.0]
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first sort your data and then use `forEach()` loop to group by first two elements and sum third element.

```js
var data = [[3,1,4],[2,1,1],[1,1,6],[1,1,1],[3,2,5],[2,2,1],[3,1,1],[1,1,4],[1,2,3],[3,1,2],[2,1,1],[2,2,2]]

data.sort(function(a, b) {
 return a[0] - b[0] || a[1] - b[1]
})

var result = [];
data.forEach(function(e) {
  var key = e[0].toString() + e[1].toString();
  if(!this[key]) result.push(this[key] = e.slice())
  else this[key][2] += e[2]
}, {})

console.log(JSON.stringify(result))
```

Answer (score 0):

Go through the sorted array, creating a new array of sums.
Create a new element when the 1st or the 2nd column become different, or add to the current element as long as those columns remain the same.

Answer (score -1):

Using Array#reduce:

```js
let arr = [
  [3.0, 1.0, 4.0], 
  [2.0, 1.0, 1.0], 
  [1.0, 1.0, 6.0], 
  [1.0, 1.0, 1.0], 
  [3.0, 2.0, 5.0], 
  [2.0, 2.0, 1.0], 
  [3.0, 1.0, 1.0],
  [1.0, 1.0, 4.0],
  [1.0, 2.0, 3.0],
  [3.0, 1.0, 2.0],
  [2.0, 1.0, 1.0],
  [2.0, 2.0, 2.0]
]


let res = Object.values(arr.reduce((a, c)=>{
  let key = c.slice(0,2).join('|'); 
  if(!a[key]){
    a[key] = c
  }else{
     a[key][2] += c[2]
  }
  return a
},{})).sort((a, b)=>{
   return a[0]-b[0] || a[1] - b[1]
});


console.log(JSON.stringify(res))
```

Basic theory is to use first 2 values to create an object key. If that key doesn't exist create a new one with current array as value.... if it already exists sum last value of each